# IOS collection View creating cell images from core data and using GCD

Tags: ios, multithreading, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, uicollectionview

I was trying to load cells for Collection view by using GCD to solve performance issue.
My codes for the loading of cells are as follows:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UICollectionViewCell *slideCell =
[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:slideCellIdentifier
                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

slideCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
slideCell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:slideCell.bounds];
slideCell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor  = [UIColor redColor];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    @autoreleasepool {
        SlideHeader *slideHeader = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(2, 2, slideCell.bounds.size.width-4, slideCell.bounds.size.height -4);

        if (slideHeader.frontCoverImage) {

            NSData *frontCoverImage = slideHeader.frontCoverImage;
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:frontCoverImage];

        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



            NSArray *visibleCells = [self.collectionView visibleCells];
            if ([visibleCells containsObject:slideCell]) {


                [slideCell.contentView addSubview:imageView];



                if (slideHeader.slideTitle.length > 0) {


                    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(slideCell.bounds.origin.x, slideCell.bounds.size.height - 30, slideCell.bounds.size.width, 30)];
                    titleLabel.text = slideHeader.slideTitle;
                    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
                    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
                    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                    titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                    [slideCell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
                }
            }
        });
    }
});


return slideCell;
```

}

I am using ARC and built in 6.1.
I believe that arc will hanld GCD memory release for me but I ended up with a problem:

Following is a screen shot of the memory use:

[image]

The momory went up as I scroll the collection view up and down continuesly.
I took a long time for the memory to get released and this causes the program to crash when the memory usage is high enough.

I tried to add autorealse in the GCD block as in my codes but this does not help releasing the memory quicker.

Can I ask what I can do to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by changing the GCD block as follows:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSData *frontCoverImage;

        if (slideHeader.frontCoverImage) {

            frontCoverImage = slideHeader.frontCoverImage;



        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



            NSArray *visibleCells = [self.collectionView visibleCells];
            if ([visibleCells containsObject:slideCell]) {

                imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:frontCoverImage];

                [slideCell.contentView addSubview:imageView];



                if (slideHeader.slideTitle.length > 0) {


                    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(slideCell.bounds.origin.x, slideCell.bounds.size.height - 30, slideCell.bounds.size.width, 30)];
                    titleLabel.text = slideHeader.slideTitle;
                    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
                    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
                    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                    titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                    [slideCell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```